# Trying to understand how range-based for loops work in C++

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector, range, auto

I've a program that reads from an input file an unknown amount of integers from a matrix and places them into a 2D vector. Once I have those integers inside the 2D vector I will output to another file each integers matching ASCII character. My problem is i was able to find a working double for loop that prints out 2D vectors but i'm unsure as to how the range inside the for loops work.

```
while(getline(in, row)){  
    int num;
    stringstream ss(row);
    vector<int> vR;
    while(ss >> num){
        vR.push_back(num);
    }
    vMain.push_back(vR);
}    

for(auto vR : vMain ){                          //<------Here
        for(auto num : vR){                     //<------Here
            if(num >= 0 && num <= 14){
                cout << " ";
                out << " ";
            }
            .
            .
            .
}
```

I created the while loop to take in the values of the file using a stringstream, then pushing back each row vector "vR" inside the main vector "vMain".

The for loops go through the vectors one value at a time then output the corresponding ASCII value, how exactly does the " : " range-based for loops work?

Comment: Add a language tag please

Answer (score -4, accepted):

std::vector actually holds 3 things *in addition to* the actual data stored. 1) a pointer to the start of the vector. 2) a pointer to the end of the vector. 3) The size of the vector.

Because of this, your loops "know" how many times to loop. It is (almost) equivalent to saying

```
for(auto i  = vMain.begin(); i != vMain.end(); i++)
```

Or even

```
for(auto i = 0; i < vMain.size(); i++)
```

Comment: There is no need for the vector to store the size, the size is a distance between `begin()` and `and()`. It stores the capacity.

Comment: Not only does this not answer the question in any way, it incorrectly explains how `vector` is implemented.

Comment: Which part of your answer explaining 'how exactly does the " : " range-based for loops work?'